# How to create and use a heap data structure

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python program that adds and removes names to a certain category.  While I'm pretty sure the use a heap would be a good method for this program, I may be thinking of the wrong data structure.  I'm still very new to programming and I am very unsure as what to do.

```
class table():
    __slots__ = ('time','volunteers')

def mkTable(time,name):
    tbl = table()
    tbl.time = time
    tbl.volumteers = name
    return tbl
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: I think a `dict` would be what you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham looks more like a `namedtuple` to me... (depending on ease of mutability)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham having said that though... OP - what do you mean by adding/removing? (as your demo code is effectively trying to emulated a `namedtuple` but your description doesn't match it)

Comment: @JonClements, I was going more by the description.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yup... I'll admit I was going by the code, then re-read the description... so I'm not quite sure what the question is - it's conflicting... I'm vtc as unclear for the moment until the OP reads the comments and edits

Comment: What is a "category" to you, and what are you hoping to accomplish once you have the names in their appropriate categories?